# why isnt the css animation backwards argument working?

Tags: css

I have a simplw div that expands and changes colors, from my understanding the backwards value for the animation-fill-mode should reset the div to the first frame of the animation after it ends, including delays, I have a delay of zero ms and instead of resetting back to the first frame, it simply disappears, why?

```
//css
@keyframes frames{
            from{
                background-color: blue;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
            }
            to{
                background-color: orange;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px; 
            }
        }

        #d1{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            animation: frames 1000ms ease-in-out 0ms 3 alternate backwards;
        }


    //html
    <div id="d1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Alternate backwards` doesn't exist. You should use `alternate-reverse`:

```
    #d1 {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        animation: frames 1000ms ease-in-out 0ms 3 alternate-reverse;
    }
```